# What does "regal optics" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here's a bit of an old Washington Post's article on Emmanuel Macron:

> In three months in power, the new head of state has been reluctant to grant interviews, preferring to deliver lengthy orations in the halls of Versailles, France's historic seat of absolute monarchy, and such **regal optics** have not played well with the media and the public.

The meaning of the bold part can be easily inferred, something along the lines of *acting like a monarch*. But when I look up *optics*, I cannot see the image the phrase is trying to create in readers' minds. How does *optics* relate to the context here?

Comment: Cambridge Dictionary [gives a very good definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/optics) of the North American usage of this word. As such I also voted to close the question, but if the definition is unclear or confusing in some way, the question could be improved.